# Import from csv scientif number representation doesn't permit any math value using Libre Office Calc

Tags: libreoffice

I have a `csv` file with some small numbers. 
When I import it with Libre Office Calc, the numbers are represented using the scientific notation.

Then when I try to do any math operation using these numbers I obtain always `#VALUE!`

Why??

Instead in the same csv I have also for example, **0** inside the cell **I1**, if I do `=I1+1` the results is `1`.

So what is the problems with other numbers?

Here an example of the file:
[image]

Comment: This seems not to be an Ubuntu specific problem and therefore off topic on this community. This question should be moved to [Super User](https://superuser.com)

Comment: @derHugo, Many questions are replied, that are generally linux or software questions, not specifically targeting Ubuntu, for example questions about `bash` or questions with a solution using `bash` command lines.

Comment: Yeah though bash is more Ubuntu specific than Libre Office .. just because it happens doesn't mean it's good

Comment: @derHugo, You have a point (I have to admit that, even if I disagree).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

Please notice that the number in column D in the screenshot in your question is right adjusted as a number, while the other numbers with a dot are left adjusted as text.

I think you have a locale that uses comma `,` instead of dot `.` to separate the decimals.

So if you convert the csv file (replace the dots with commas) before you import the data, it should work.

### Conversion with `tr`

You can use `tr` to replace the decimal dots with commas. It is a good idea to check first (in an editor) that there are no 'other dots' that you want to preserve.  For example, there are probably commas that separate the columns, and you should convert them to tabs before you replace the decimal dots.

So for example (use your own file names)

```
< csv-dot.txt tr ',' '\t' | tr '\.' ',' > csv-comma.txt
```

**Example**

```
$ echo 5.4e-07,4.00e-07>csv-dot.txt
$ < csv-dot.txt tr ',' '\t' | tr '\.' ',' > csv-comma.txt
$ for i in csv-*;do echo -n "$i: ";cat "$i"; done
csv-comma.txt: 5,4e-07  4,00e-07
csv-dot.txt: 5.4e-07, 4.00e-07
```

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't notice that.. How can I do that? Is it possible do it using a script?

Comment: @Teo, There is a description in the answer, how to convert the csv-file.